# Submitting search form using urllib2 (python)

Tags: python, urllib2, cookielib

I am trying to search for courses in my school's system and logging in works with my login info

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib,re

username = 'user'
password = 'pass'

# Login main site
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'userid' : username, 'pwd' : password})
opener.open('https://psns.cc.stonybrook.edu/psp/he90prods/?cmd=login', login_data)
```

Trying to find courses does not work, here is what I have

```
# Fill in Class search criteria
search_data = {'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_CATALOG_NBR$73$': '575', 'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$':'AMS'}
request = urllib2.Request('https://psns.cc.stonybrook.edu/psc/he90prods/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/SA_LEARNER_SERVICES.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL', urllib.urlencode(search_data))
response = opener.open(request)
print response.read()
```

Here is what I see

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmk0C.jpg

Here is what is supposed to appear if done correctly

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSOuJ.png

(can't post images yet..)

What am I doing wrong with the search form?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `urllib2.Request()` is the `POST` data, not the `GET` query string. You can send the query string by directly attaching it to the URL:

```
request = urllib2.Request('https://psns.cc.stonybrook.edu/psc/he90prods/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/SA_LEARNER_SERVICES.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL?' + urllib.urlencode(search_data))
```